# SQL Server two foreign keys for same column in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in my table which are both the same foreign key of another table.

These are my two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    user_id integer IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE notizen_aktionen 
(
    notiz_aktion_id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
    notiz_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aktion_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    creation_user_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    status_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    last_user_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(notiz_aktion_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (creation_user_id) 
         REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (last_user_id) 
         REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
);
```

One value contains the `user_id` of the user who created the record and the other one holds the information who has made the last change to this record.

What I want to achieve now is when the user will be deleted, both of these columns should be set to null.

So I thought of using a foreign key for this. But SQL server won't let me create this table. In MySQL this works just fine.

I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint '%.*ls' on table '%.*ls' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2019?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Microsoft's recommendation is still to [use a trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-PL/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1785-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of cascades to keep the data's integrity when two foreign keys reference the same table.

If there's a cleaner, DRI solution to this problem, I'd like to know it, too.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a design flow and you would probably need to normalize your table. Read what Microsoft [suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1785-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16) here. If you cannot alter the design, you need to use triggers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).